# I need to change UUID to another UUID

Tags: grub2, fstab

update:

hello you both many many thanks for your answers - i am very very glad to hear from you  - see the full story: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/if-i-close-the-lid-the-notebook-does-not-shutdown/83103/3    - i do not know how to apply the changes!?

Love to hear from you  - best regard

here the full story ... see all 
I have an unique situation where I need to change UUID to another UUID. 
I formatted it and obviously number changed... I know I need these files changed. But I cannot find anywhere on the net info about customizing UUID.

the issues:  when closing the lid - the notebook does not poweroff - or shutdown

i need to change

> UUID=ae33e597-0c72-4c66-9f16-6606322111c3 swap swap defaults,noatime 0
>   2

to this

> UUID=ae33e597-0c72-4c66-9f16-6606322111c3 swap swap defaults

how to achieve that!?

btw: see the hibernation issues i have had so far

```
martin-pc martin]# cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
# be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
# disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=A790-35CD                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=1bf0c824-0645-47da-b8a1-88eaaabecc33 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=ae33e597-0c72-4c66-9f16-6606322111c3 swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
[martin-pc martin]# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='Manjaro'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet resume=UUID=ae33e597-0c72-4c66-9f16-6606322111c3"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# If you want to enable the save default function, uncomment the following
# line, and set GRUB_DEFAULT to saved.
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
#GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command 'videoinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black"
GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="green/black"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/usr/share/grub/background.png"
GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/manjaro/theme.txt"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
[martin-pc martin]#
```

**btw** - i have had some issues -. with the hibernate due to a hung up upgrade process (that was interrupted unfortunatly=)

If we use ext for it:

```
tune2fs /dev/{device} -U {uuid}
```

From man tune2fs

```
-U UUID
```

> Set the universally unique identifier (UUID) of the filesystem to
>   UUID.  The format of the UUID is a series of hex digits separated by
>   hyphens, like this: c1b9d5a2-f162-11cf-9ece-0020afc76f16. The UUID
>   parameter may also be one of the following:
>
> clear  clear the filesystem UUID random generate a new
>   randomly-generated UUID time   generate a new time-based UUID
>
> The UUID may be used by mount(8), fsck(8), and /etc/fstab(5) (and
>   possibly others) by specifying UUID=uuid instead of a block special
>   device name like /dev/hda1.

Comment: You sound a little confused. You say you need to change a UUID, but in your "change to" example, there's no new UUID, and both statements are wrong for swap anyway. What partition did you format, and why, and how? You can see the new UUID with `sudo blkid`. Then edit /etc/fstab. Please clarify so I can give you a complete answer.

Comment: During upgrade which can takes hours it is advised to turn off suspend and hibernate. Also to make sure laptop is plugged in during the upgrade process. Did you crash during 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade, or 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade or some other upgrade?

Comment: hello you both many many thanks for your answers - i am very very glad to hear from you  - see the full story: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/if-i-close-the-lid-the-notebook-does-not-shutdown/83103/3    - i do not know how to apply the changes!? 
Love to hear from you  - best regard

Comment: This site only supports Ubuntu. You're running Manjaro 18.04. Sorry.